# Why is my footer displaying like this

Tags: html, css, footer

I seem to be having a small problem with the footer on my website.
I have swapped around the code in regards the order it appears in the styling and the html.

Any advice appreciated

[Picture of the footer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xesdQ.jpg)

```
.left{
    text-align:left;
    float:left;
}
.right{
    float:right;
    text-align:right;
}
.centered{
    text-align:center;
}

<div class="footer-container">
    <footer class="wrapper">
        <div id="footer">
            <p class="left"><img src="img/map25-redish.png"/> Curaheen, Cork </p> 
            <p class="right"><img src="img/telephone65-blue.png"/> </p>
            <p class="centered"><img src="img/envelope4-green.png"/ </p>
            <br/><br/>
        </div>
    </footer>
```

Comment: It's unclear what's going on without all of the CSS. Is this using Bootstrap? Is there any chance you can post a Codepen example?

Comment: Quite unclear. What's wrong exactly? What do you intend to do?

Comment: of course, here you go https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Jyyred

Comment: @PierreLeBot its not displaying in line the center is slightly raised above left and right

Comment: You are to show a complete example that shows the problem here, not CodePen: [mcve]

Comment: Your html is invalid with your third image. Also, `<img>` and `<br>` do not use or need a closing slash.

Answer (score 1):

I would go further than Alexis's answer with a more modern approach using flexbox:

```css
#footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  /* adjust margin and padding beow to suit your design */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#footer li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#footer li img {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="footer">
    <li><img src="http://fakeimg.pl/40"/>Curaheen, Cork </li>
    <li><img src="http://fakeimg.pl/40"/>Email address</li>
    <li><img src="http://fakeimg.pl/40"/>Phone number</li>
</ul>
```

That way, the children elements inside `#footer` will take the space they need, with the same order they are in the HTML, letting space between them (`justify-content` property) and centered vertically (`align-items` property).

We follow the same procedure for `LI` children to align images with text (`align-items` property)

You'll have to adjust the margin and padding to suit your design, of course.

Comment: Great idea but be aware that flexbox aren't fully supported by IE 10 yet :)

Comment: True. But there is MS properties that can do the job to fit the standards, especially for something trivial like this. And IE10 is losing market shares anyway (yay!)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it looks like it's a floating problem. To solve this you have many solutions as playing with margin or line-height.

But my advice would be to use a ul list, display your li items in inline-block and give them a width of 33%.

Float remove your elements from the normal flow.

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
}

footer {
  background: #eee;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

ul {
  display: block;
  
  width: 100%;
  
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <ul>
    <li>#01</li>
    <li>#02</li>
    <li>#03</li>
  </ul>
</footer>
```